# Complex objects cannot be referenced multiple times by the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 5 together with fluent mapping API. I have an entity that uses 2 complex types, however if I load the entity and then commit changes to the EF DBContext without any changes to the entity I get the following error;

> Complex objects cannot be referenced multiple times by the same entity.

I've spent a good few hours trying to understand why this is happening. Can anyone shed any light on this issues??

Comment: possible related: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1307

Comment: Read that article and understand that limitation of EF, however I am not using the same type of complex type within the entity, I am using 2 complex types which are completely different types.

Comment: Ok, but still it can be related and it was not clear from your question. Can you maybe try out with EF6?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually got to the bottom of this issue after several hours. My issue was that my entity inherited from a base class which was overriding GetHashCode. Removing this from the base class and everything started working.

Comment: The real problem is with the equal, if they are equal for ef its the same object